# Mongo DB creating field structure

Tags: mongodb

Im new to Mongodb could any one help me , how to create a structure in mongodo,where in sql create table tablename('id','name',age); can be achieved

Comment: schemaless mean that you don't need to define a structure [Read this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless)

Comment: i dont have any schema.just i want to create a structure .where the values are not inserted.

Comment: Can you please add details to your question to explain what you actually want. The answers that don't answer your question are a reflection of you not asking properly. Use the edit link on your question and explain with some detail.

Comment: "_id" : ObjectId("542297eb90129586a1360bee"),
 "age" : "",
 "email" : "kathy@yahoo.com",
 "name" : "kathy"  its my student collection in which fields with values are inserted .. now i want only to create the structure with no field values

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you create collections, example:

```
>db.createCollection("mycol", { capped : true, autoIndexID : true, size : 6142800, max : 10000 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }

>db.mycol.insert({
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   name: 'MongoDB', 
   age: 24
})
```

More documentation.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_quick_guide.htm

Comment: thanks for reply .i dont want to insert values..just want to create the collection structure with fields